# Nesting VueJS Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wanted to try to nest components in my vue files:

The parent is implementing the component GISDispatches.vue. This should represent a table later on in the master page. So to test the whole thing, I want to see how the methods are working alltogether. I would expect in this setup, that the child method `loadDispatchTable` gets called and returns the console output.

**Component Parent**

```
<script>
    import GISDispatches from '../components/GISDispatches.vue';

    export default {
        template: require('../templates/map.html'),

        components: {
            gisdispatches: GISDispatches
        },

        events: {
            MapsApiLoaded: function() {
                this.loadDispatchTable;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Component Child - GISDispatches.vue**

```
<script>

    export default {
        template: require('../templates/GISDispatches.html'),

        data() {
            return {
                dispatches: ''
            }
        },

        computed: {
        },

        events: {
        },

        methods: {
            loadDispatchTable: function() {
                console.log("OK");
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

But the console output does not appear, still the page is loaded as expected. Did I need to change the setup?

Comment: You are missing the () to call your function in the parent mapsapiloaded listener